# Why doesn't the following HTML/CSS code appear on Drupal sites?

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

The following HTML with CSS inline shows up correctly in the editor, but not when it's saved. what's the reason? I've checked it with Drupal 7 and Drupal 8 (if you wan't to quick-test it yourself: [simplytest.me](https://simplytest.me/))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Responsive CSS Tabs</title>



      <style>
      @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700");
@import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css");
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #111;
  background: #fafafa;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

label[for*='1']:before {
  content: '\f1cb';
}

label[for*='2']:before {
  content: '\f17d';
}

label[for*='3']:before {
  content: '\f16b';
}

label[for*='4']:before {
  content: '\f1a9';
}

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #6EC8D7;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid #6EC8D7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  label {
    font-size: 0;
  }

  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}

    </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>Responsive CSS Tabs</h1>

<main>

  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>

  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>

  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>

  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Drupal</label>

  <section id="content1">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content3">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet beef venison beef ribs kielbasa. Sausage pig leberkas, t-bone sirloin shoulder bresaola. Frankfurter rump porchetta ham. Pork belly prosciutto brisket meatloaf short ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Brisket meatball turkey short loin boudin leberkas meatloaf chuck andouille pork loin pastrami spare ribs pancetta rump. Frankfurter corned beef beef tenderloin short loin meatloaf swine ground round venison.
    </p>
  </section>

  <section id="content4">
    <p>
      Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet landjaeger sausage brisket, jerky drumstick fatback boudin ball tip turducken. Pork belly meatball t-bone bresaola tail filet mignon kevin turkey ribeye shank flank doner cow kielbasa shankle. Pig swine chicken hamburger, tenderloin turkey rump ball tip sirloin frankfurter meatloaf boudin brisket ham hock. Hamburger venison brisket tri-tip andouille pork belly ball tip short ribs biltong meatball chuck. Pork chop ribeye tail short ribs, beef hamburger meatball kielbasa rump corned beef porchetta landjaeger flank. Doner rump frankfurter meatball meatloaf, cow kevin pork pork loin venison fatback spare ribs salami beef ribs.
    </p>
    <p>
      Jerky jowl pork chop tongue, kielbasa shank venison. Capicola shank pig ribeye leberkas filet mignon brisket beef kevin tenderloin porchetta. Capicola fatback venison shank kielbasa, drumstick ribeye landjaeger beef kevin tail meatball pastrami prosciutto pancetta. Tail kevin spare ribs ground round ham ham hock brisket shoulder. Corned beef tri-tip leberkas flank sausage ham hock filet mignon beef ribs pancetta turkey.
    </p>
  </section>

</main>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You pasted all of that into an editor?

Comment: Yes (of course, I've chosen Full HTML). I also separated it into a CSS file and went just with the HTML in the editor. Works fine on other sites, [see Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qROxao), but not on Drupal. And I tried that on different sites.

Comment: The way you are doing it is bad. @XinNod I take it a your a newbie to Drupal? You need to learn to do this the Drupal way, using template files and your theme to achieve your results.

Comment: This is a great example of what not to do.

Comment: @No Sssweat See comment above: "I also separated it into a CSS file".

Comment: `I also separated it into a CSS file` That's a small step in the right direction. The only thing that should be in your editor is the actual paragraphs and without the `<p></p>` tags, since [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor), which comes with Drupal 8 core, will create those for you.

Comment: Really, <p></p> ... Check the source code in your editor, No Sssweat.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "text filter", ideally this kind of stuff doesn't go into a text field and is stored as a CSS file. It's likely that the text filter is set to "Filtered HTML", which will strip anything that isn't basic text formatting html, images, etc.

The text filter that will allow this stuff through is "Full HTML"

Comment: That was also my first thought. And even Full HTML has sometimes restrictions set. But even if all restrictions on Full HTML are unchecked, it still doesn't work out. For some weird reason it appears correctly in the editor itself, though.